Eastern European Film about a man who carries his own coffin to his grave
Plot: 
An old man must give his life to settle a family feud.  He carries his own coffin on a bus to another part of an Eastern European country.  Young tourists join him on the journey and film the trip; including the final scene where he has a heart attack.  Since he died before being shot to settle the score the aggrieved family tries to shoot a young relative traveling with him.
The American name of the film is the same as another well known domestic film.  This is a film I would like to own.
Period: Contemporary.
Country of origin: I was thinking Belarus but I'm not sure. But I am confident it was former Soviet Union but not Russia.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? What time period was it about? What country was it likely from? What language? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.
